# Debugging HXT performance problems

Tags: performance, debugging, haskell, memory-leaks, hxt

I'm trying to use HXT to read in some big XML data files (hundreds of MB.)

My code has a space-leak *somewhere*, but I can't seem to find it. I do have a little bit of a clue as to what is happening thanks to my very limited knowledge of the ghc profiling tool chain.

Basically, the document is parsed, but not evaluated.

Here's some code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Control.Monad (liftM)

main = do file <- (liftM head getArgs) >>= parseTuba
          case file of(Left  m) -> print "Failed."
                      (Right _) -> print "Success."

data Sentence t = Sentence [Node t] deriving Show
data Node t = Word { wSurface :: !t } deriving Show

parseTuba :: FilePath -> IO (Either String ([Sentence String]))
parseTuba f = do r <- runX (readDocument [] f >>> process)
                 case r of
                      []   -> return $ Left "No parse result."
                      [pr] -> return $ Right pr
                      _    -> return $ Left "Ambiguous parse result!"

process :: (ArrowXml a) => a XmlTree ([Sentence String])
process = getChildren >>> listA (tag "sentence" >>> listA word >>> arr (\ns -> Sentence ns))

word :: (ArrowXml a) => a XmlTree (Node String)
word = tag "word" >>> getAttrValue "form" >>> arr (\s -> Word s)

-- | Gets the tag with the given name below the node.
tag  :: (ArrowXml a) => String -> a XmlTree XmlTree
tag s = getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName s
```

I'm trying to read a corpus file, and the structure is obviously something like `<corpus><sentence><word form="Hello"/><word form="world"/></sentence></corpus>`.

Even on the very small development corpus, the program takes ~15 secs to read it in, of which around 20% are GC time (that's way too much.)

In particular, a lot of data is spending way too much time in DRAG state. This is the profile:

[image: http://imgur.com/YC3jh]

monitoring DRAG culprits. You can see that decodeDocument gets called a lot, and its data is then stalled until the very end of the execution.

Now, I think this should be easily fixed by folding all this decodeDocument stuff into my data structures (`Sentence` and `Word`) and then the RT can forget about these thunks. The way it's currently happening though, is that the folding happens at the *very* *end* when I force evaluation by deconstruction of `Either` in the `IO` monad, where it could easily happen *online*. I see no reason for this, and my attempts to strictify the program have so far been in vain. I hope somebody can help me :-)

I just can't even figure out too many places to put `seq`s and `$!`s in…

Answer (score 1):

One possible thing to try: the default hxt parser is strict, but there *does* exist a lazy parser based on tagsoup: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-tagsoup

In understand that expat can do lazy processing as well: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-expat

You may want to see if switching parsing backends, by itself, solves your issue.

Comment: Well, I actually chose HXT over Hexpat because I could do fairly flexible and well-defined XML parsing.
I have written an online parser that uses polyParse on top of Hexpat. That does its job, but is not as easily extensible and debuggable as HXT.

I'll give hxt-tagsoup a try.